# How to display code in the same line?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code:

```
<div align="left">
© 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA - All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://uhlhosting.ch">UHL Hosting</a>
</div>
<div align="right">
    <a href="/agb">AGB</a>
</div>
<div align="right">
    <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a>
</div>
```

I want `/agb` and `/impressum` to be on the right side and the copyright section on the left side.

How can I do this without external CSS? Desired result is like in this screenshot – only that it should be on the same line:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check below HTML

HTML

```
<div align="left" style="float: left; width: 650px;">© 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA - All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://uhlhosting.ch">UHL Hosting</a>
</div>
<div class="rightmain" style="float: right; width: 100px;">
 <div align="right" style="float: left;">
  <a href="/agb">AGB</a>
 </div>
 <div align="rightnew" style="float: right;">
  <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I inline this CSS in the same HTML code? I do not want to involve other files, just one code and to do it all.

Comment: no need for a border it was just drawen by me to show that the AGB and Impressum is not on same line as Copyrighted text.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to your code for position: inline-block. Since it looks like you do not have any margins the classes below should work okay for you. You can add it inline in the head tag or put the CSS properties in separate CSS file and link it in.

`
    .right {
    position: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    }

```
.left {
position: inline-block;
width: 50%;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            © 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA - All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://uhlhosting.ch">UHL Hosting</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"  style="text-align: right">
           <a href="/agb">A3B</a>
    <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would prefer to avoid external CSS of any kind. I already solved the issue, thanks to @Dhaval's answer.